# How do I install Chemtool?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, make

I've downloaded the `chemtool-1.6.14.tar.gz` from [here](http://ruby.chemie.uni-freiburg.de/~martin/chemtool/chemtool-1.6.14.tar.gz). Then I extracted its contents into the directory: `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14` then I opened terminal, cd'ed to this directory, ran `./configure` (with no errors), then ran `make` from the terminal and received this output:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14'
Making all in m4
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14/m4'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14/m4'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14/po'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14/po'
Making all in src-cht
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14/src-cht'
gcc -g -O2 cht.c -o cht
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14/src-cht'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14'
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I.    -g -O2 -c main.c
main.c:18:22: fatal error: gdk/gdkx.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gdk/gdkx.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fusion809/Downloads/chemtool-1.6.14'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages indicate that you have not installed the development libraries.

Since chemtool is in the repositories (Universe) you just need to install it via software-center

[image: Install chemtool]

However - if you do wish to alter the code - then remember to install the dependencies first:

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep chemtool
```